AHK script loop is not working after using hotkey or replace
using this code:
Loop
{
    WinWait, Untitled - Notepad
    WinClose, Untitled - Notepad
}

I want to keep any new notepad windows closed automatically.
And then I want to add a keyboard shortcut to exit AHK script: Esc::ExitApp
but when I add Esc::ExitApp the loop seems not working and notepad windows will not be closed automatically while code is still running:
Esc::ExitApp  ; ==> this line is causing the loop to malfunction and not work as expected

Loop
{
    WinWait, Untitled - Notepad
    WinClose, Untitled - Notepad
}

Why this is happening and how can I make it work as expected?!

Unlabeled code that follows a return, is unreachable and will never execute.
The hotkey
Esc::ExitApp  

is a single-line hotkey which has an implied return.
To work around it add the hotkey after the loop:
; === auto-execute section (top of the script): ===

Loop ; performs one or more statements repeatedly and is no label
{
    WinWait, Untitled - Notepad
    WinClose, Untitled - Notepad
}

; === end of auto-execute section, because of this hotkey:

Esc::ExitApp

For details see
Auto-execute Section,
Loop
Labels

Your answer seems to be correct and working fine but I did not understood your logical reason. According to your description I tried to add label for loop andalso multiline hotkey with return (some other workarounds) but it only worked if I place hotkeys after loop. And if the problem is only from return, how multiple hotkeys are running after an infinite loop?! They should not work with such logic because the code sould be trapped in loop or at least stop/exit after first hotkey which is a single line return and other hotkeys after first hotkey should fail to work like the loop.

Please, read my edited answer and have a look on the added links. If there is something you don't understand, feel free to ask.

Thanks for the helpful references; I've read them all. Maybe the AHK code logics are too complicated for me to understand deeply. But your answer was very helpful for my case.

In this case the auto-execute section is executed repeatedly (because of the Loop)  until you press Escape to terminate the script.

This is the exact magic happening here which I can not understand. How the code reaches to Escape while escape is not included somewhere in the loop block! Logically code never will reach to there in any other programing languages and this is AHK magic!

A timeout is implemented in all system and script activities for checking whether other activities are triggered.
